# select users who currently view same page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I find several partial solutions in answers on this question, but common answer seems to be absent.
So, I have a table users with columns user_id, user_name. On each static page of website I want to display all user names of users who currently view this page.

1. Should I have a table views with columns user_id, webpage_link?
2. If yes, when I shall update data in column webpage_link? How to connect code from following answer with mysql database [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active) ? (If it is ok for this purpose.)
3. To make updates very often is not very good. So, the user can view several pages (for example, in 2 or more tabs). What type of webpage_link column shall be in this case?

Answer (score 0):

1. With every http request, you get a $path variable. if you also have a logged in user, you can store which page this user requested last (e.g. in a table like you described, but only storing the relative path).
2. You update this information on a per-request-basis in some sort of front-controller. (just make sure you put it where it is called for every authenticated page). When the users session times out, you remove the row of that user from the table.
3. this case is a little more difficult. you could store the last n pages/paths the user has requested and leave the rest as above. You don't have to change the table structure for that, just allow for multiple rows per user. (the combination user_id+path should be unique, though)

Hope that helps to get you started

Comment: Everything is clear except 2). When user left page, I shall delete corresponded row. How to do this? Also about 3) the way to count all user rows  before adding new one seems to be not very efficient.

Comment: 2) you can try to send an ajax-request to the server to remove that page from the user's entries on e.g. `$(window).unload()`

Comment: 3) i am not sure I understand what you mean. you don't have to check whether the user_id/path combo exists, in mysql you can just use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (check the docs)